# How to render a value of a single variable to a template using Django?

Tags: django, templates, view, render

I am building a web application where the completion of the project (status) is returned to the client(user) through a dynamic URL. The view looks something like this:[Click here to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnFoT.png)

I want to retrieve the single value from `phase` field (phase field stores integer values from 1 to 10) and perform `percentage = (phase / 10) * 100`. How can I render the query `phase` and render `percentage` variable which stores the percentage, to template?

Here's my model.py:

```
from cmath import phase
from pyexpat import model
from django.db import models
from sqlalchemy import delete

class Project(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Inititated', 'Inititated'),
        ('Paused', 'Paused'),
        ('In progress', 'In progress'),
        ('Aborted', 'Aborted'),
        ('Completed', 'Completed')
    )

    PHASE = (
        ('1', '1'),
        ('2', '2'),
        ('3', '3'),
        ('4', '4'),
        ('5', '5'),
        ('6', '6'),
        ('7', '7'),
        ('8', '8'),
        ('9', '9'),
        ('10', '10')
    )

    p_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    p_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    c_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    c_mail = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    init_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    ect = models.DateField(null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, choices=STATUS)
    collabs = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    phase = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, choices=PHASE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.p_name
```

views.py:

```
from cmath import phase
from multiprocessing import context
import re
from unicodedata import name
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Project
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

# views
def dashboard(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', {'projects':projects})


def status(request, no):
    projects = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=no) 

    return render(request, 'accounts/status.html', {'projects':projects})
```

status.html (template):

```
<div id="greeter">
                <h1 id="name">Hello, {{projects.c_name}}!</h1>
                <p>Your project has come this far</p>
            </div>
            <div id="frame_body">
                <div id="percentage"><h1 id="receivedVal">80<sup>%</sup></h1></div>
                <div id="proj-name"><p>{{projects.p_name}}</p></div>
                <div id="name-of-staff-head"><p>Handled by Mr. X</p></div>
                <div id="temporary">
                    <p>Status -{{projects.status}}</p> <br>
                    <p>Phase -{{projects.phase}}</p> <br>
                    <p>Collaborators -{{projects.collab}}</p> 
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is the percentage dynamic as in, will it change every n number of seconds/minutes/hours or it will be static - you need its value only once?

Comment: What would you like to achieve exactly? You can add a model property returning your percebtage value: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods

Comment: @antpngl92 Yes it will be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

First of all, assuming you want `phage` to be a whole number - don't store numbers as strings in your database (phase field). Instead, use an `IntegerField` with constraints to limit the number that can be stored:

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    foo_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_foo_count_range",
                check=models.Q(foo_count__range=(1, 10)),
            ),
        ]
```

Or alternatively, you can use field validators, read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/validators/)

Then you can create an API (whatever it suits you - class/function based), for instance: (more on APIView [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/))

```
class GetValue(APIView):
    class OutputSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        phase = serializer.IntegerFiled()

    def get(self, request, project_id):
        project = get_object_or_404(Project.objects.only('phase'), id=project_id)
        data = self.OutputSerializer(project).data
        
        return Response(data)
```

Now you can write javascript to call every n seconds/minutes your API and display the newly fetched data.

In addition, you can make the conversion (`percentage = (phase / 10) * 100`) in you API view so your front end would get what it needs without making any calculations OR as @Marco suggested as a model method.